# Formatting this Equation, I have tried several things that are not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I have created a Data Validation list (4 items) in A16:A22 works great, now in B16:B22 I need to take the choice from A16 and have it pull from a list specific to the choice in A16, I have tried multiple things and can not get this part, once I have this I will then create, the quantities of what they chose in B16 for instance in C16. So if the Product in A16 is Letterhead then in B16 I want it to recognize that under letterhead they have threechoices, I want them to be able to choose from the list the one they want (Bank Letterhead, HC Letterhead, or 2nd Page of Letterhead), then in C16 I want to be able to have a list of quantities for them to choose from (1000, 2500, 5000, 10M, 15M, 25M, 2nd Page 100 only), I hope that makes sense and is something that can be done. I am sure it is but I am doing something worng, Please help.

I have tried Conditional for matting with sumif(s), I have tried creating data validations. I have called an excel training center that I have attended classes and they were unable to help me unless I attend a class in August, I need this by the end of the month.

=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(A$16$,"LETTERHEAD",Details!$B$52), I have tried listing it out with if functions for each item, and what I want it to return.

It just returns exactly what I typed in not actual list of data I am trying to get, or just clears out all that I have typed and doesn't return an error message or anything.

Comment: Sounds like you want a form instead, like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhsCNTV5KFA

Comment: Or this: https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand my answer, you need to understand the concept of **Names** in Excel and have some understanding of **Data Validation** and **INDIRECT** formula.

An important step is to give names to the lists, and refer to the Name of the list when setting up data validation.

In this case there could be three tiers of list,

**Tier 1 - A16 to A22**: List_Grp

**Tier 2 - B16 to B22**: List_A, List_B, List_C, List_B

**Tier 3 - C16 to C22**:

Qty_A1, Qty_A2, Qty_A3, Qty_A4;

Qty_B1, Qty_B2, Qty_B3, Qty_B4;

Qty_C1, Qty_C2, Qty_C3, Qty_C4;

Qty_D1, Qty_D2, Qty_D3, Qty_D4

For simplicity purpose I only set up four lists in Tier 3 but the logic is the same for setting up the rest.

Let me know if there is any question in relation to my solution below.

[image: Solution]